# BDB LongBinding vs ByteArrayBinding static methods

Tags: java, static-methods, berkeley-db

In the `LongBinding` class, the methods `entryToLong(DatabaseEntry entry)` and `longToEntry(long val, DatabaseEntry entry)` are both static.

But in the `ByteArrayBinding` class, `entryToObject(DatabaseEntry entry)` and `objectToEntry(byte[] object, DatabaseEntry entry)` are both not static.

The implementations of these methods seem very similar. For example, upon examining the source code, one can see that both the `longToEntry` and `objectToEntry` methods are delegating to `entry.setData`, where `entry` is a method parameter with type `DatabaseEntry`.

Why are these two `LongBinding` methods static, while the analogous `ByteArrayBinding` methods are not?

In my pom.xml, I have the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sleepycat</groupId>
  <artifactId>je</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really an explanation.

The methods in `ByteArrayBinding` could (and should?) have been `static` as they have no reference to the instance of the class.

Those two classes have probably been written by different developpers and they implemented the functionality a bit differently.

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping wouldn't be the correct one. But alas, oh well :)